# Is it possible to embed just one element from a webpage using an iFrame/code?

Tags: iframe, gis, embed

I specifically am trying to get an iframe/url/whatever works for embedding a specific chart from a website (interactive map), and wonder if it is possible. The interactive map link is [here](https://nwcc-apps.sc.egov.usda.gov/imap/#version=169&elements=&networks=!&states=!&counties=!&hucs=&minElevation=&maxElevation=&elementSelectType=any&activeOnly=true&activeForecastPointsOnly=false&hucLabels=false&hucIdLabels=false&hucParameterLabels=true&stationLabels=&overlays=&hucOverlays=2&basinOpacity=75&basinNoDataOpacity=25&basemapOpacity=100&maskOpacity=0&mode=data&openSections=dataElement,parameter,date,basin,options,elements,location,networks&controlsOpen=true&popup=&popupMulti=&popupBasin=&base=esriNgwm&displayType=station&basinType=6&dataElement=WTEQ&depth=-8&parameter=PCTMED&frequency=DAILY&duration=I&customDuration=&dayPart=E&monthPart=E&forecastPubDay=1&forecastExceedance=50&useMixedPast=true&seqColor=1&divColor=7&scaleType=D&scaleMin=&scaleMax=&referencePeriodType=POR&referenceBegin=1991&referenceEnd=2020&minimumYears=20&hucAssociations=true&relativeDate=-1&lat=43.993&lon=-111.929&zoom=5.0). Below is the chart I am trying to embed -- I would ideally not have to embed the chart home page which includes a rather large header.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5pWv.jpg)

I have tried using the iframe that is shown in the picture, but have not had luck with that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.